# What is the difference in the registry and registry hives

Tags: c#, .net, registry

When I run the following command, rKey has two values.

```
RegistryKey sqlServer = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server", false);
```

When I run either of the following commands (on the same machine as the same user) I find no values;

```
 RegistryKey sqlServer64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey( RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

   RegistryKey sqlServer32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey( RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32 );
```

Can anyone point me to the answer or a description of the hives vs plain registry access?

Edit:
What I do afterwards is :

```
 StringBuilder sbKeys = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (var key in sqlServer.GetValueNames() )
  {
       sbKeys.AppendLine( key );
  }
```

For all RegistryKeys. For sqlServer I see two Values, for sqlServer32 and SqlServer64 there are no values.

Comment: You need to show what you do with `sqlServer64` and `sqlServer`. Where does `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"` come into the second variant?

Comment: You'll have to use OpenSubKey() next.

Comment: Well, to be fair to me, my very first comment shows that both Hans and I strongly suspected the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your second variant is that you have failed to open a sub key. Your `sqlServer.GetValueNames()` call operates at the root level of a particular hive.

You need it to be like this:

```
RegistryKey root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey sqlServer = root.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
foreach (var key in sqlServer.GetValueNames())
{ .... }
```

Done this way it's no different from your first variant (apart from the registry view). I expect that using the appropriate registry view will lead to the solution to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853683/registrykey-getvalue-returns-no-value-in-installer).

<sub>Naturally you'll want to add some error checking to the code above.</sub>

Comment: Thanks David, I took the hint from Hans' comment on my post and do already fell stupid (and after that fixed the issue). Although the accept will go to Hans!